# Como fazer de projeto do Wamp para o Lamp

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos, laravel-rotas

Tenho um projeto laravel que terminei feito no Windows (wampserver) utilizando o Laravel 5.2 no php 5.5.12 funcionando perfeitamente.

Gostaria de saber como faço para copiar ele para o servidor que é em CentOS 7.
Que é PHP 7. Se eu instalar o Laravel nele ele pega o Laravel 5.5.

Tentei copiar o projeto para o servidor e separar a pasta public do resto do projeto, mas ele só acha a rota principal, que no caso é o meu login

minha Rota está assim:

> **app\routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::post('/logar', 'UsuarioController@logar');
```

Quando tento logar, dá o erro 404

> The requested URL /myproject/logar was not found on this server.

Ele já está com as permissões

Meu formulario de login está assim:

> **login.blade.php**

```
        <form action="{{ action('UsuarioController@logar') }}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" name="login">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8">

                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Logar</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
        </form>
```

Meu controller está assim:

> **UsuarioController.php**

```
    public function logar(){
        echo "Principal";
    }

    public function login(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function sair(){
        Session::flush();
        return redirect(  )->action( 'UsuarioController@login' );
    }
```

Detalhe:

Se eu criar um projeto Laravel no próprio CentOS, funciona perfeitamente.

Apenas precisei acrescentar o bloco no httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/portal/myproject">    
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks    
    AllowOverride all    
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Com certeza errei em alguma coisa, mas onde?

Comment: Jovem, isso não tem a ver com LAMP, WAMP ou  XAMPP. O problema é que você programou em uma versão do PHP (com uma versão do Laravel) e está tentando fazer a publicação usando **uma versão mais nova** tanto do PHP quanto do Laravel. O PHP em si já tem alguns problemas de compatibilidade entre versões menores, imagina a diferença que não deve ser do PHP 5.x para o PHP 7. O PHP 7 é pra ser completamente diferente dos anteriores. Talvez você até consiga fazer sua aplicação "rodar", mas vai acabar encontrando problemas no meio do caminho.

Comment: @LINQ além do que falou, estou achando que o problema pode ser Mod_Rewrite faltando no servidor novo o que acha ?

Comment: @Otto Sim, o problema inicial, bem provavelmente, é só com o Apache mesmo.

Comment: o mod_rewrite está ativo

Comment: Então não é possível? Tenho que criar outro projeto no servidor e copiar meu código pra lá?

Answer (score -1):

abre o arquivo public_html/index.php e modifica o diretório original:

**require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/autoload.php';**

**$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';**

para

**require __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';**

**$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/app.php';**

Comment: Fiz e não funcionou

Comment: foi um exemplo, tipo, deve estar de acordo com os diretórios de onde você hospedou, caso esteja em outra pasta, tem que inserir o diretório certinho!